# checking if a string with asterisk(*) is present within another string

Tags: c, algorithm, search

I am working on a program to check if a particular string is present in the given string: that is if one string is sub string of another string.

For example:

> 1)**String**: YoungPeople  -->   **Substring to be checked**: ungPeo
>
> ```
>   The output should return true.
> ```
>
> 2)**String**: Hello How are You? --> **Substring to be checked**: l*are
>
> ```
>     The output should return true.
> ```

I have used the naive based searching algorithm and it works perfectly fine for the first input.

But I am having trouble in the second kind of input where the asterisk(*) is present which should be treated as a regular expression: i.e. matches zero or more characters.

How should I check for the sub string having an * sign?

Should I try to use the same naive algorithm for searching the character before * and for the string after it?  Or is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You already provided a good approach. Try it and see if there is any problem with it.

Comment: I think this is not a trivial task. you should check both possibilities - that you are reading the * or a concrete text. the best way is to use the an actual regular expression library.

Comment: strchr doesn't work for you?

Comment: Do you mean wildcards? Windows API PathMatchSpec() can do this, or fnmatch() on linux

Comment: This looks more like glob pattern matching than a regex.

Answer (score 3):

**How should i check for the sub string having an * sign?**

Upon reading a `*`, you need to try 1-2 below.

**... use the same naive algorithm for searching ... is there a better approach ...?***

There are better methods.  A *recursive* one follows.

[Edit note: 6/10 found/fixed bug]

As you progress through the string, use recursion to check the rest of the string.
The `*` simple allows for 2 candidate paths:
1) advance the `str`
2) advance the `substr`
Else a matching `char` allows advancing both.

```
// StarCompare() helper function
bool StarCmp(const char *str, const char *pat) {
  if (*pat == '\0') return 1;
  if (*pat == '*') {
    if (*str) {
      // advance str and use the * again
      if (StarCmp(str + 1, pat)) return 1;
    }
    // let * match nothing and advacne to the next pattern
    return StarCmp(str, pat + 1);
  }
  if (*pat == *str) {
    return StarCmp(str + 1, pat + 1);
    }
  return 0;
}  

bool StarCompare(const char *str, const char *pat) {
  if (!str || !pat) return 0;
  do {
    if (StarCmp(str, pat)) return 1;
  } while (*str++);
  return 0;
  }
```

---

[Edit Test code in previous version]

Answer (score 2):

The [GNU Regex Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) seems like what you are looking for.  If you are not familiar with regular expression, check [this site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: Probably overkill -- fnmatch(3) seems like a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you have to do:

1. Split the search string by the * character
2. Look for each of the parts (in the correct order) in the string you are searching

Alternatively, you can use regexes as other people have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to look for a well-written implementation of glob matching would be the bash sources.  But here's a simple recursive implementation that works:

```
#include <assert.h>

int
_glob_match(char * pattern, char * str)
{
  if (!*pattern)          return 1;
  if (!*str)              return 0;
  if (*pattern == '*')    return match_any_tail(pattern + 1, str);
  if (*pattern != *str)   return 0;
  else                    return _glob_match(pattern + 1, str + 1);
}

int
match_any_tail(char * pattern, char * str)
{
  for (; *str; str++)
    if (_glob_match(pattern, str))
      return 1;
  return 0;
}

int glob_match(char * pattern, char * str)
{
  return match_any_tail (pattern, str);
}

void
main()
{
  assert(glob_match("ungPeo", "YoungPeople"));
  assert(glob_match("l*are",  "Hello How are You?"));
}
```

Comment: No, that would let pattern "abc" match string "abbc".

Comment: @chux You're absolutely right about the "abc", "abbc" case - thanks.  It turns out though that if you change `*pattern != *str` to a failure, then `match_any_tail` gives the correct glob-matching behavior for this case and the two in the question.